# How to remove first appearance in stream when searching for duplicates?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a Stream of objects, which define the equals and hashcode based on an id that they have. So I know that using `stream.distinct()` I will get a stream that does not have any duplicate, but it will keep the first appearance, rather than the last one.

This is clearly stated in the docs:

> For ordered streams, the selection of distinct elements is stable
>        * (for duplicated elements, the element appearing first in the encounter
>        * order is preserved.)

So how can I have a stream that doesn't have duplicates, but keeping the last appearance instead?

For example if I have this list of items `1,2,3,1,4,5`.

If I apply the `distinct()` I will get `1,2,3,4,5`, and I am expecting: `2,3,1,4,5`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try reversing the order, removing duplicates then and reverse the order again?

Comment: Reverse stream. Take distinct. Reverse result.

Comment: I seriously doubt you can achieve this using streams.  This would require the stream functions to either "look ahead" to see if a duplicate appears later in the stream, or go back and retroactively remove an item that was already allowed through into the output.  Neither of those is really part of streams' "character".

Comment: Why do you even care whether the "first" or the "last" element remains in the stream? If they are _equal_, it really shouldn't matter!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose just because I care of the order

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose You don't know enough about the OP's use case to say whether it matters or not.

Comment: @rollback will try that!

Comment: @ajb *"You don't know enough about the OP's use case to say whether it matters or not."* - I doubt that the OP really understands the meaning of  *equals*.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle What is your basis for that statement?  I see no evidence to support it.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle believe me, I know the meaning of equals. You don't seem to understand my question (maybe I wan't really clear)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle if two objects are equal, then it doesn't mean that its position in a list "doesn't matter" ... two ordered lists that have the same items, in a different order, are not equal lists :). Do you know the meaning of equals?

Comment: With regard to reversing the stream: If the stream's source is an array or `ArrayList`, there are fairly simply ways to generate the reverse stream.  If it's most other structures, or if you all you have is a `Stream` and don't know the source, you will have to generate a reverse stream by storing all the elements in an intermediate list.  At that point, I have to question whether it's worthwhile to use a stream at all.  Using the "reverse" solution would require more passes through the input than necessary, I think.

Comment: @PabloMatiasGomez No, your meaning is clear.  You want to transform (1,2,3,1,4,5) to (2,3,1,4,5) instead of (1,2,3,4,5).  I don't know why, but I assume there's a good reason in your application.  I cannot figure out why there are comments that assume that wanting this particular result means you don't understand what's going on.

Comment: @PabloMatiasGomez *"if two objects are equal, then it doesn't mean that its position in a list "doesn't matter""* -  in that case a `List` may be the wrong data structure to store the items...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Maybe you're not reading carefully.  He is saying the order of the items does matter, which means a `List` (or array) is definitely the right data structure, since lists are ordered.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I am using a Stream... that is ordered... is that so complicated? And just so you know, `List`s are ordered..

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I have to second Pablo and ajb on this. Pablo's request is crystal-clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A customized `toMap` collector with access-order `LinkedHashMap` is a good start, for example:

```
Stream.of( 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5 )
        .collect( Collectors.toMap(
                key -> key,
                value -> value,
                ( oldValue, newValue ) -> newValue,
                () -> new LinkedHashMap<>( 16, 0.75f, true )
        ) )
        .values()
        .stream()
        .forEach( System.out::println );
```

The task of preserving the last appearance of an item implies that you will have to fully consume the original stream anyway before producing the first element of the new stream, so collecting and creating a new stream is not that bad. Reversing, applying distinct, and reversing again, as suggested in comments, will fully consume both the original and "distinct" stream, so using a specialized collector should be better.

Answer (score 3):

[Oleg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44912907/1876620) is absolutely correct, here I'm posting other ways of doing the same thing, based on his idea of using an *access-ordered* `LinkedHashMap`.

Without streams:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(16, 0.75f, true); // access order
Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5)
    .forEach(e -> map.put(e, e)); // just put
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(map.values()); // discard the map

System.out.println(list1); // [2, 3, 1, 4, 5]
```

With streams, using a custom collector:

```
List<Integer> list2 = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5)
    .collect(Collector.of(
        () -> new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>(16, 0.75f, true),
        (m, e) -> m.put(e, e),
        (m1, m2) -> { m1.putAll(m2); return m1; },
        m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())));

System.out.println(list2); // [2, 3, 1, 4, 5]
```

Note: as pointed out by Holger in the comments, it's important to use `Map.values()` instead of `Map.keySet()` to create the result list. This is because when `m.put(e, e)` is used, if an entry with the same key already existed in the map, the old value is replaced with the new value, but the key remains the same, i.e. the old one.

Comment: There is a small difference to the other answer. `put` will move existing entries to the front, but not replace the key instances. For boxed small integer values, where equal values always have the same identity, this makes no difference, but in use cases where the object identity matters, the result will be wrong. But that’s easy to fix; just use `values()` instead of `keySet()`. Besides that, it’s simpler to add type parameters to the `LinkedHashMap`, i.e.  `() -> new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer>(16, 0.75f, true)`, instead of `Collector.of`.

Comment: @Holger OK, then this is a bug of IntelliJ's type inference mechanism. I reported it and it was already reported. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by first reversing the list, removing the duplicates and then reversing it again to get the original.

```
public void removeDuplicates(){ 
     Collections.reverse(duplicatesList);
     duplicatesList = duplicatesList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
     Collections.reverse(duplicatesList);
     }
```